# 120vac to 24vac transformer for sprinkler/irrigation solenoids - lightweight solutions?

Tags: transformer, relay

I am putting together a DIY IOT relay to control my sprinkler system.  My relay controller requires 5VDC, the sprinkler solenoids are the standard 24VAC.   I'm planning on a single plug (120VAC) in, then splitting the 120 to separate 5VDC (for the relay controller) and 24VAC (for the solenoids).

My question is in regards to the proper 120VAC->24VAC transformer to use.

I believe sprinkler solenoids don't use more than a few hundred mA.  My issue is finding a transformer for this project.

Regular (industrial?) transformers like this one:
[https://www.amazon.com/Packard-Control-Transformer-Class-Mount/dp/B01HPJT7C0/ref=sr_1_19?keywords=120vac+to+24vac&qid=1583520933&sr=8-19](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HPJT7C0)

Weigh almost a pound and a half, whereas wallwarts such as this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Apas-Sprinkler-Adapter-Transformer-Irrigation/dp/B0784S9358/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=120vac+to+24vac+power+adapter&qid=1583519910&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0784S9358)

are rated for lower amperage, but also weigh less than half a pound.  If I bought a wall wart, I'd have to try to extract the transformer, which I don't want to have to deal with if possible.

Are there any 120VAC->24VAC transformers readily available that aren't as heavy as paperweights?

My goal is to fit everything (PCB, 2 transformers) in a plastic enclosure that is hopefully lightweight.

Edit: The unit will be indoors, along with all the power sources.

Comment: Using a wall wart to get 24V means you can keep mains out of your plastic enclosure ... and further away from water.

Comment: It would be hlepful if you privided more detail about your intended packaging and form factor.  Since you're touching mains power, that *really matters*. See also yesterday's question on DIY.SE regarding UL-listed outdoor 24V transformers.

Comment: I’d like to see your face when you open up a wall wart looking for a transformer that will work in your application.

Comment: @Andyaka: It's a 24 V AC output so it might be a good old-fashioned trafo like from when we were kids and lugging around guitar and PA amplifiers.

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear in the OP, the enclosure and power sources will all be indoors.  I plan on putting the components in a plastic box no bigger than a standard sprinkler controller box.  I know I can separate the power inside of its own enclosure, but then the situation would be 2 cables going into my relay box.  Maybe a better idea would be doing 120>24vac in its own enclosure, then a stepdown 24vac->5vdc inside the relay box, which would probably still be a better idea than mains going to it.  Thank you for the ideas thus far as well.

Comment: @Transistor Looks like that one is a standard low frequency transformer, it's just smaller from being a lower rating. The 40VA AC wall warts are still big, and run fairly warm, there's a few of them scattered around my workplace, mostly the type that use the socket coverplate retaining screw for additional support.

Comment: How many solenoids are you powering? That will determine the power you need. I'd agree with your approach to just bringing 24V into the box, then using maybe a bridge rectifier and a small DC-DC module to generate the 5V supply.

Comment: @PhilG I have 6 solenoids, but only plan on powering one at a time.  In case the relay goes haywire and tries to open many at once, I may put in maybe a 500mA - 1A fuse inline.  If I proceed using a 24vac wall wart, I'll need to calculate my solenoid and controller mA requirements, and I'd still need to find a 24vac -> 5vdc transformer/rect, and am not sure the best place to find one (amazon doesn't seem to be the place).  I don't have the knowledge to build a rect/module myself for the 24->5 conversion.

Comment: I'm still having trouble finding a single 24vac to 5vdc transformer, so I'm thinking about doing the step down in two stages:
24vac to 12vdc
https://www.amazon.com/Urban-Security-Group-Converter-Adapter/dp/B0722LM36T/ref=sr_1_2
12vdc to 5vdc:
https://www.amazon.com/KNACRO-Supply-Step-Down-Converter-Synchronous/dp/B07GTHK99K/ref=sr_1_19

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

my soldering iron runs at 26VAC  and to install a 12V timer I used a bridge rectifier and a LM2596HV buck module. (which cost a about a buck)  they have adjustable output voltage so you could turn it down to 5v to for your relay controller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5E51H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note:- peak rectifier output is ~1.4*24V = 34V, so the rectifier and capacitor should be rated for 40V or higher.

Comment: also +10%   LM2596*HV* mentioned for that reason, but yeah I could have made a bigger deal.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's rated as AC output it is most likely a standard mains frequency transformer. The DC wallwarts are almost all switched-mode power supplies for size, lightness and cost.

To ensure that you don't draw more current than the rating wire the relays as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd9cms.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Arranging relay contacts as shown ensures that only one solenoid can be switched on at a time. The left-most relay to be energised will take precedence over all the others.*